# Get all the orders for ItemId 1 and 2 simultaneously

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have scenario below. I have a table Orders(OrderId, ItemId) and i want to get all the orders where ItemId 1 and 2 is coming simulataneoudsly

```
OrderId ItemId
1000      1
1001      2
1002      1
1002      2
1002      3
1003      1
1003      2
1004      4
1004      5
1005      3
1006      1
1006      3
```

as per above table's data and the ask ....i should get output OrderId 1002 and 1003.

Answer (score 3):

Use `COUNT` and `HAVING`:

```
SELECT OrderId
FROM Orders
WHERE
    ItemId IN(1, 2)
GROUP BY OrderId
HAVING COUNT(ItemId) = 2
```

If duplicate `ItemId` is allowed in an `OrderId`, use:

```
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ItemId) = 2
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/591224)</kbd>

Comment: @Matt That's what I thought too. I'll include that.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, using nested queries, would be:

```
SELECT orderId
FROM ORDERS o
WHERE o.itemId = 1
AND EXISTS (SELECT 'X'
              FROM ORDERS o1
             WHERE o1.orderId = o.orderId
               AND o1.itemId = 2);
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/591226)</kbd>